# php with mysql connection, securing script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently I am writing a simple register/login/reset password script in php and I am curious if do I have to especially take care of "%" sign in user inputs. I am using mysql_real_escape_string, but I don't know where "%" can make me into trouble. Any tips?

Comment: That's only of significance in `LIKE` clauses. Or did you come across some specific warning / previous question / article that prompted your question?

Answer (score 0):

The best advise I could give you is to [use prepared statements](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Database_Cheat_Sheet).